# How to search a folder for a specific word on Mac

Tags: bash, macos, shell, command-line, spotlight

So I have a folder which has a bunch of files (source code) and other folders. I want to search this folder for a word, say, faceGroup, and get all the files that contain this word and also get locations of these files. How to perform this action effectively and efficiently (maybe using terminal or spotlight)?

Comment: `grep -R -l directoryName word`

Comment: Also you may try with `find` [How do I find a file by filename in Mac OSX terminal?](https://superuser.com/a/226571)

Comment: Open the folder in Finder, type Cmd-f, then enter the word you want to search for.

Comment: @Barmar Doesn't seem to work. To test, I typed `grep -R -l . scan` and it returned `grep: scan: No such file or directory`.  The word `scan` does exist in a file in this directory.

Comment: Oops, got the order wrong. `grep -R -l word directoryName`

Comment: You have a folder and some other folders. Where do you want to search exactly? In the first folder or the others? Or both? How did you get folders on a Mac - they are a Microsoft invention - Macs have directories.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to search folder.

```
mdfind kind:folder "Huddl-Backend"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 3rd party app **EasyFind**. It will search in files and folders and list where all matches occur. You can also narrow your search to a specific disk or folder. EasyFind is free and available from the app store.